# Static generic delegate field in C#

Tags: c#, generics

Using generic types is nice and easy, but since I tried to implement my own generic types, I came to a problem which I couldn't solve by myself yet. I want to have a static field for a delegate. This is how it works for me when using non-generic types:

```
delegate Type Type_Delegate(Type type);
static Type_Delegate TypeMethod = new Type_Delegate(TypeMethodName);

// Now the TypeMethod can be called like this from somewhere in the Code:
ClassName.TypeMethod(typeof(string));
```

But when using any generic type:

```
delegate T Type_Delegate<T>(T type);
// This static field syntax isn't allowed:
static Type_Delegate<T> TypeMethod = new Type_Delegate<T>(TypeMethodName);

// It would be a dream to be able to use it like this now:
ClassName.TypeMethod<string>("Hello world!");
```

T is unknown type/namespace.

When I experiment with the syntax:

```
// This static field syntax isn't allowed, too:
static Type_Delegate TypeMethod = new Type_Delegate(TypeMethodName);
```

Type arguments are missing for usage.

I tried several ideas about the possible syntax, but not succeed...

How do I need to change the static field syntax to work as assumed, so the code is able to set a generic delegate method as value, without having to specify a type at that time?

**Edit**: I also tried to wrap the delegate and field with a generic static class, but there I still have the same syntax issues, when I want to set the field value without specifying the type.

**Edit 2**: Maybe the following example workaround apporach will clarify my thoughts more, since I think most commenters didn't understand my goal (maybe it's my bad English, too):

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;

namespace Testing
{
    public static class GenericTest
    {
        public interface IGenericClass<T>
        {
            T Method(T parameter);
        }

        public class GenericClass<T> : IGenericClass<T>
        {
            public T Method(T parameter)
            {
                // Just a stupid example, don't think about that...
                return parameter;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// The value must be any type that implements the IGenericClass<T> interface
        /// </summary>
        public static Type GenericField = typeof(GenericClass<>);

        /// <summary>
        /// Call the method of an instance of the type that was set to GenericField
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="T">The type to use for creating an instance of the generic class</param>
        /// <param name="parameter">The parameter for calling the method of the generic class</param>
        /// <returns>Any value of type "T"</returns>
        public static dynamic GenericMethod(Type T, object parameter)
        {
            var genericType = GenericField.MakeGenericType(new Type[] { T });
            MethodInfo method = genericType.GetMethod("Method");
            if (method == null) throw new InvalidCastException("GenericField isn't a IGenericClass<T> type");
            return method.Invoke(Activator.CreateInstance(genericType), new object[] { parameter });
        }
    }
}
```

Now I can do something like this somewhere else in the code:

```
MessageBox.Show(Testing.GenericTest.GenericMethod(typeof(string), "Hello world!"));
```

In this example solution I need to work with classes and an interface, require reflections, it's a whole bunch of code required to get the same functionality for a generic (class-)method, as I can get with only two lines of code when working with non-generic methods (using delegates). What an overhead, what a hack - I try to avoid doing such nasty things in productive code. But if there are no better 2 lines of Code that do the same, this time I will have to fight my ego...

Comment: I don't think that's possible. The value of the generic type needs to be determined at compile time. Same way you can't instantiate a `List<T>`.

Comment: At initialization time  Type Parameter type must be determined

Comment: @Rotem In theory it should be possible from the logic apporach. But maybe it isn't implemented in the compiler (yet).

Comment: "In theory it should be possible from the logic apporach." I don't know what you mean by that. The language simply prohibits it. Note that aside from anything else, fields cannot be generic. If you put that field within a generic class declaring a type parameter `T`, it will at least remove the first issue...

Comment: It doesn't make sense because static variables belong to the class not the instance.

Comment: @user10797322 It makes no sense to me logically as well. What do you expect to get when you `new` an unknown type?

Comment: @Rotem I've just added more Information in hope it will clarify my goal a bit more. It's just about a method that I want addins to be able to overwrite with their own method. This works for non-generic methods using a delegate - but for a generic method there seems to be no solution with only 2 lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, by wrapping it in a generic class definition and using the class type parameter.

```
static class C<T>
{
    public static DelegateTypePrototype<T> DelegateType;
}
```

This way the type only has to be resolved once you "request" an instance of the class. At least that's my intuitive understanding coming from C++ templates background.

Comment: That's a way more clean solution. It will initialize a static instance of `C` and its members for every type of `T` used, but I don't have to use slow reflection and "dynamic". The disadvantage is, I have to set the delegate for `DelegateType` for every type that may be used for `T`.